# Redirect one url to another url using .htaccess in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, codeigniter-3

I am trying to redirect these URLs:

http://www.example.com/welcome/index

http://www.example.com/welcome

http://www.example.com/index.php

To this URL:

http://www.example.com/

Using a rewrite rule.

I have tried this (which isn't working):

```
Redirect 301 http://www.example.com/welcome/index$ http://www.example.com/
```

Comment: That's what routes are for: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Comment: @Alex my default controller is welcome and it is already redirect all the links to my base url but i want to change the url also mean to say that when i open this example.com/welcome/index then the url changes to example.com thanks a lot

Comment: is this the only controller on your site?

Comment: What is your $config['base_url'] in config file?

Comment: @Alex no this is not the only controller but acc. to seo all the links must refer to base url which is https://www.example.com/

Comment: @Kamlesh $config['base_url'] = 'https://www.example.com/';

Comment: I still don't understand why you want to do this. You can easily generate a seo friendly url just by structuring your controllers properly e.g. example.com/products/toy-car ... And in ci *all* links will refer to the base url or site url as long as you use the url helpers. In your example the likelihood someone goes to welcome/index as opposed to just your site url having defined the welcome/index as the default controller is very small as long as you don't explicitly reference welcome/index... Irregardless, do you plan on writing reqrite conditions for every controller to prevent

Comment: user from seeing somecontroller/index? Sounds unnecessary.

Comment: @Alex google picks up all those url in his error list and keep sending me the error list . my seo guy give me the solution to force these urls to base url . so , i need that . if you pls help me. thanx in advance

Comment: error list? what error list? you mean 404 errors? that's an entirely separate problem. and you should probably just remove the `$` sign. but my knowledge of .hta is limited. i'm just trying to understand but i guess you have your reasons. just sounds like you are going to have fun doing this for every controller

Comment: @Alex Redirect 301 /oldpage.html http://www.example.com/old_page then it will redirect me to http://www.example.com/old_page?/old_page.html
instead of http://www.example.com/old_page

Comment: `Redirect 301 http://www.example.com/welcome/index http://www.example.com/`

Comment: i have alrady done that but this is not working... @Alex

Comment: Works for me dunno

Answer (score 0):

Please add your below code in your route .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Additionally, check your `$config['base_url']` and add your base url:

```
$config['base_url'] = http://localhost/project/
```

Then it will work like as charm and you will redirect to another controller without the index.php

```
Example:  http://localhost/project/home
```

---

Use of index function:

```
 www.example.com/welcome/index
```

If you need to use index function in URL, For that Please set route in routes file.

Please check it with as above

Comment: well i have already done that. this code is used to remove index.php from the url . but how can do that when someone type this in url section www.example.com/welcome/index & www.example.com/welcome  then the url automatically change to www.example.com

Comment: no not exactly when someone type www.example.com/welcome/index then the url shown in url clumn is www.example.com

Comment: Yes, @deep if you have not provided route for that then you will get this issue always.

Comment: in routes it is not working when someone wrote this url www.example.com/welcome/index & www.example.com/welcome , www.example.com/index.php then it it will force the url to www.example.com which is the base url of our project .please help me i am stuck since 10 days

Comment: Please update your code based on my code and set routes like $new_route['welcome/index'] = 'welcome/index';
$new_route['welcome'] = 'welcome/index';

It will work

Comment: He wants the page to not be routed but to redirect to base so that the physical url changes.